# flutter iOS build got failed (ld: library not found for -lPods-Runner)

Tags: build, dart, flutter

I am new to flutter. I have created small flutter app and i wanna test it on my real devices but i am unable to generate ios ipa file for testing. Please if anyone could help me with this issues then it would be good for me.thanks in advance!! I getting this error . :

```
*iMac:test_app snehal$ flutter build ios
Building com.org.testApp for device (ios-release)...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: 5GC7G69Y22
Starting Xcode build...                                          
Xcode build done.                                            5.1s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **

=== BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===
ld: library not found for -lPods-Runner
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) Encountered error while building for device.*
```

Comment: see [flutter iOS build failed (ld: library not found for -lPods-Runner)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53020495/flutter-ios-build-failed-ld-library-not-found-for-lpods-runner)

Comment: Thanks. It helped