# Flutter library not found for -ldevice_info, can't archive the ios app with xcode

Tags: xcode, flutter, archive

when I try to archive the app or run in a real device, I always get below errors:

```
ld: library not found for -ldevice_info
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

but if I just run in a simulator, everything is ok, if I try to remove the device_info package, then it will also show another package not found:(

I am using the latest flutter dev sdk, and I have setup a valid iOS developer certificates.

Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I found the solution for me in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53020495/flutter-ios-build-failed-ld-library-not-found-for-lpods-runner

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the solution here in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53020495/flutter-ios-build-failed-ld-library-not-found-for-lpods-runner) as mentioned in the comment works for this case:

> In new projects, in the iOS part is necessary to adjust a few
> parameters, such as signing, and that you can only do in Xcode.
>
> So, try to open the iOS project with Xcode and try to build it from
> there. You'll see better warning and error messages there, specially
> regarding signing.
>
> You can open Xcode and locate your project `ios` folder, or:
>
> ```
> cd yourproject/ios
> open -a Xcode .
> ```
>
> Then select `Product > Run` in the menu.

Also, [this GitHub post discussion](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/51417) could also be a possible reason for other cases. Try to [check the following](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/51417#issuecomment-591754783):

> I was able to successfully archive with your pubspec.yaml.
>
> 1. Can you confirm you opened `ios/Runner.xcworkspace` and NOT `ios/Runner.xcodeproj`? See [Better handle case where a developer
>    opens `Runner.xcodeproj` instead of `Runner.xcworkspace`
>    #10770](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10770).
> 2. Did you run flutter build ios before you Archived? See https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios#create-a-build-archive.